# Subject math GRE exam 0568 Q.47

Tags: vector-analysis, gre-exam

The question and its answer is given in the following picture:[image]

I do not exactly from where the second equality in the following line came, could anyone explain it for me?

[image]

Comment: $d\gamma = \frac{d\gamma}{dt} dt$

Comment: Check any vector calculus text (or a multivariate calculus text) for more info on line integrals. This stuff also happens when you deal with differential forms.

Comment: The *fork* done by $\mathbf F$?  A solution that doesn't look exactly right?  Is this from a Kaplan® book?

Comment: I do not think so.@tilper it is written by Charles Rambo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution doesn't look exactly right. First, let us define work, the work done by a force $\bf{F}$ along a path $C$ (a curve in the space), is equal to line integral

$$W = \int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf l.$$
Where, $d\mathbf{l}$ is a vector line element.

By definition, we have, as u can see here: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition_2)

$$\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf l = \int_a^b \mathbf{F}(r(t)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) dt,$$
where $\mathbf r$ is a parametrization of the curve $C$, such that $\mathbf r(a)$ and $\mathbf r(b)$ match the endpoints of C.

It's the right form of the second equality.

--

By the way, the force is not equal to the vector $(-1,0,1)$, actually it is 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,0,1)$, since $F=|\mathbf F| =1.$

Comment: why$ F = |\mathbb{F}| =1$?

Comment: The question assert that $\mathbf F$ is a constant **unit** force.